# Python UTC to iso format now working- cast error

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am getting datetime in UTC format from datafactory in databricks.
I am trying to convert it into databricks timestamp and insert into database.

```
Format that i am  receiving: 2020-11-02T01:00:00Z
Convert into : 2020-11-02T01:00:00.000+0000 (iso format)
```

i tried to convert the string into isoformat()

```
df.selectExpr("make_timestamp(YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND) as MAKE_TIMESTAMP")
```

and then

```
spark.sql("INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 1, 'IMPORT','"+ slice_date_time.isoformat() +"','deltaload',0, '0')")
```

But when i try to insert it I am receiving error:

- Cannot safely cast 'start_time': string to timestamp
- Cannot safely cast 'end_time': string to timestamp;

I also tried making timestamp. but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Using Spark DataFrame API:

```
# create dataframe
list_data = [(1, '2020-11-02T01:00:00Z'), (2, '2020-11-03T01:00:00Z'), (3, '2020-11-04T01:00:00Z')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(list_data, ['id', 'utc_time'])

# make sure to set your timezone in spark conf
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, date_format
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')

df.select("utc_time").withColumn('iso_time', date_format(to_timestamp(df.utc_time, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"), 
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    ).alias('iso_time')).show(10, False)


+--------------------+----------------------------+
|utc_time            |iso_time                    |
+--------------------+----------------------------+
|2020-11-02T01:00:00Z|2020-11-02T01:00:00.000+0000|
|2020-11-03T01:00:00Z|2020-11-03T01:00:00.000+0000|
|2020-11-04T01:00:00Z|2020-11-04T01:00:00.000+0000|
+--------------------+----------------------------+
```

Try to store iso_time directly into database, if your database supports different datetime format try to adjust

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ